# Sometimes WebRTC data channel messages are not received

Tags: webrtc

When I send binary data channel messages over WebRTC, sometimes the messages are not received.

I use JUnit and Selenium to launch multiple browsers, either locally or using BrowserStack, either headless or "headful". Each browser uses an HTML page to publish a stream via WebRTC to the same server, and all publishers specify the same data channel label. The Java test uses Selenium to call JavaScript functions on the page to send and receive messages. When any publisher produces a message, the other publishers sharing that data channel label are expected to received it. Often, they do.

One the server side, I can see that 100% of the sent messages were received by the server and distributed to the other publishers as expected. I can see the datagram was produced and delivered to the networking layer for each receiving publisher.

Yet in Chrome, sometimes the message is not received. There is no TSN gap reported to the server. I have intentionally created TSN gaps by dropping chunks at the server side as they are being packetized, and when I do that, Chrome does report TSN gaps and fills the missing packet as expected.
With additional verbose Chrome logging, I still don't find the missing messages nor any correlated errors, although I do find the raw bytes of the messages that my JavaScript message handler actually receives (the non-missing messages). I think this rules out an error in the receiving side JavaScript functions, because Chrome logs `text_pcap_packet_observer.cc` independently.
When starting Chrome, I specify the logging options:

```
--enable-logging
--v=1
--log-file=<logFilePath>
```

and also fake devices:

```
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
--use-fake-device-for-media-stream
--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=<audiofile>
--use-file-for-fake-video-capture=<videofile>
```

and if test options indicate headless, then

```
--headless=new
```

I have reduced the size of the messages so that they fit into a single chunk (the messages are currently 1024 bytes). I have tried various data rates, as slow as 2000 bytes per second, to no avail.

Currently developing a TCP-only test to rule out UDP problems, but if it were the case that a UDP packet has gone missing (obviously a possibility) then why doesn't the server request to fill the missing TSN gap? Otherwise, if the server did receive the chunk, what happened to it after that? Why isn't it logged by `text_pcap_packet_observer.cc`? Why isn't it delivered to the JavaScript handler?